# Alignment of the text like a table

Tags: macros

What I wanted to achieve was this:
[image]
I defined a new command like this:

```
\newcommand{\details}[2]{
#1 \hspace{2cm} : #2 \\
}
```

The full MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newcommand{\details}[2]{
#1 \hspace{2cm} : #2 \\
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\details{Name}{Subham Soni}
\details{Date of Birth}{March 22, 1994}
\details{Nationality}{Indian}
\details{Address for Communication}{XXXYYY}
\end{document}
```

What I get is this:

[image]

Now, two things:
1) Even after adding `\noindent`, there is a slight indent
2) The colons aren't aligned.

What I wanted the command to do was, what ever be text(Name, DOB, etc.), leave 2cm after it and then print the colon. Also, if the text is two long, then the text must break and appear after the colon only

How do I do it?

Comment: You can also try the `listliketab` package. It provides pretty much everthing you need for these kind of problems and it's easy to handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `tabular` as Jubobs has mentioned. This is an attempt to correct your approach. You are adding a horizontal space of 2cm after the first word. Then  the `:` is placed 2cm to the right of the first word. That is why they are not aligned vertically. Remedy is to put the first word inside a box of some length and then, put the `:`.  You can actually calculate the width of widest first word and set the width of your box.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\mylen}
\setlength{\mylen}{\widthof{Address for Communication}}
\newcommand{\details}[2]{%
\makebox[\mylen][l]{#1} \,: #2 \\
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\details{Name}{Subham Soni}
\details{Date of Birth}{March 22, 1994}
\details{Nationality}{Indian}
\details{Address for Communication}{XXXYYY}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a solution using `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft]{article}
\usepackage{calc,showframe}
\newlength{\mylen}
\setlength{\mylen}{\widthof{Address for Communication}}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{\widthof{:}}
\newcommand{\details}[2]{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\mylen}
#1
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{2mm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\mylength+2mm}
:
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-6mm-\mylen-\mylength\relax}
 #2 \par
\end{minipage}
\par\noindent
\ignorespaces
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\details{Name}{Subham Soni}
\details{Date of Birth}{March 22, 1994}
\details{Nationality}{Indian}
\details{Address for Communication}{This is going to be some long address This is going to be some long address}
\end{document}
```

This is a `tabular` solution (improvised Jubobss' solution)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{calc,array}
\newlength{\mylen}
\setlength{\mylen}{\widthof{Address for Communication}}
\newcommand{\details}[2]{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\mylen}!{:}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-\mylen-4\tabcolsep\relax}}
#1 & #2 
\end{tabular}%
\par\noindent
\ignorespaces
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\details{Name}{Subham Soni}
\details{Date of Birth}{March 22, 1994}
\details{Nationality}{Indian}
\details{Address for Communication}{This is going to be some long address This is going to be some long address}
\end{document}
```

And this one uses `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\newcommand{\details}[2]{%
#1 & #2  \\
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[t]{@{}>{\bfseries}l!{:}X}
\details{Name}{Subham Soni}
\details{Date of Birth}{March 22, 1994}
\details{Nationality}{Indian}
\details{Address for Communication}{This is going to be some long address This is going to be some long address}
\end{tabularx}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can you come for a personal chat please

Answer (score 2):

The "slight indent" is caused by the spurious space at the beginning of `\details`'s definition.

If you want a `tabular`-like output, why not use a `tabular` environment?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand*{\details}[2]{% <--- there was a spurious space here
  \textbf{#1} & : #2 \\
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{2cm}}l}
\details{Name}{Subham Soni}
\details{Date of Birth}{March 22, 1994}
\details{Nationality}{Indian}
\details{Address for Communication}{XXXYYY}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @subhamsoni What do you mean?

Comment: A Table will have cells (rows and columns) but, here it has a similar structure too but its not a table. Confusing right?

Comment: @subhamsoni I'm not sure I understand, but perhaps you're confusing `table` and `tabular` environments. The important question is: does the output suit you?

Comment: Yes. I am satisfied with it

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer `parboxes` instead of `tabulars`. In any case I think `tabular` is better because it computes columns widths automatically, while in this case you need to know the largest line.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\details}[2]{%
\parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright \strut#1\strut} : \parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright \strut#2\strut}\\
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\details{Name}{Subham Soni and some more text to see what happens}
\details{Date of Birth}{March 22, 1994}
\details{Nationality}{Indian}
\details{Address for Communication}{XXXYYY and some more text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should, at least, add `\strut` before and after `#2`; but the vertical spacing between stacked parboxes will not be uniform.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `\parbox`. The code will look like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newcommand{\details}[2]{\noindent\strut%
  \parbox[t]{.48\textwidth}{\raggedright\strut#1\strut}\ :\ % add 2cm if you wish
  \parbox[t]{.5\textwidth}{\raggedright\strut#2\strut}\par}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\details{Name}{Subham Soni}
\details{Date of Birth}{March 22, 1994}
\details{Nationality}{Indian}
\details{Address for Communication}{XXXYYY}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]